# angular-xeditable doesn't work well within ui-bootstrap <uib-tabset> element

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, x-editable

I embed a Angular-xeditable inside a uib-tabset element, however the form can't be submitted.

Please check the code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/itDFMD?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<uib-tabset>
  <uib-tab>
    <uib-tab-heading>
      <a href=# editable-text="name">{{name}}</a>
    </uib-tab-heading>

  </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab heading="Tab2">
    Static Content.
  </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab heading="Tab3">
    Static Content.
  </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab>
    <uib-tab-heading>
      <a role="tab" uib-tooltip="Add a new release." tooltip-placement="right" tooltip-append-to-body="true">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
      </a>
    </uib-tab-heading>

  </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Thank you.